# IDF.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'inputCol'

Tags: machine-learning, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, nlp

```
idf = IDF(minDocFreq=3, inputCol="filtered", outputCols="filtered_idf")
idfModel = idf.fit(regexTokenized)
TFIDF_featurized = idfModel.transform(regexTokenized)
```

> TypeError: IDF.**init**() got a`your text`n unexpected keyword argument 'inputCol'

Comment: Always check the documentation: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.mllib.feature.IDF.html The IDF class does not have those parameters, so the error is correct.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such parameter in the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.mllib.feature.IDF.html).